# on Properly embedded submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $S$ be submanifold of $M$ such that every smooth function f : S → R has a smooth extension to a neighborhood U of of $S$ in M.

My attempt: I have shown that under the given condition $S$ ie embedded submanifold. Thus it suffice to show that $S$ is closed in $M$ to show that $S$ is properly embeddded. Suppose $S$ is not closed in $M$. Then there is a point $p\in \overline S-S$. If I can construct a smooth function on  $M$ that is zero only at $p$, then $\frac{1}{f}$ is smooth on $S$ but has no extension to all of $M$ since $p$ is a limit point of $S$. Please provide me some hints.

Comment: Do you mean: "[...] under the given condition $S$ is a properly embedded submanifold"?

Comment: Yes. The question is to show that $S$ Is properly embedded submanifold.

Answer (score 1):

Take a smooth function  $h\colon \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow [0,1]$ with $h(0)=1$ and $h(x)<1$ for $x\neq 0$. (For example
$h(x)=\exp(-\vert x\vert^2/(1-\vert x\vert^2))$ for $\vert x\vert <1$ and $\equiv 0$ otherwise).

Then choose a chart $(U,\varphi\colon U\xrightarrow{\sim}\mathbb{R}^n)$ of $M$ with $\varphi(p)=0$ and put $f(q)=1-h(\varphi(q))$ for $q\in U$ and $f(q)=1$ if $q\notin U.$ Then $f$ is smooth on all of $M$ and only vanishes in $p$.

Comment: Very helpful. What not clear for me is the smoothness of $f$, say how the two definitions agree on on $\partial U$

Comment: Let $B\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ the compact unit ball and $K:= \varphi^{-1}(B)\subset U$. Not that $h(x)=0$ for $x\notin B$ and hence $f(q)=1$ for $q\in U\backslash K$. Since $K\subset U$ compact,  it stays away from $\partial U$ and thus in a neighbourhood of $\partial U$, $f$ is constant and thus smooth.

Comment: Or more formally, prove the following Lemma: *Suppose $M=A\cup B$ is a cover by open sets and $a\in C^\infty(A)$, $b\in C^\infty (B)$ with $a(q)=b(q)$ if $q\in A\cap B$. Then there is a smooth function $f$ on all of $M$ with $f\vert_A = a$ and $f\vert_B = b$.* Then in the case at hand, let $A = M\backslash K$ and $a\equiv 1$ and $B= U$ and $b(q) = 1- h(\phi(q))$ for $q\in U$.

Comment: Ok. More precise.